# How to add a button to bottom of UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, toolbar, uipageviewcontroller

I would like to add a button to my UIPageViewController just like the bottom right button of the [iOS Weather app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzaRo.jpg).
I would like to know what is most correct and clean way of doing it.
Should I access the PageControl somehow and add a subview with the button I want to add or should I hide the Page Control and add a toolbar at the bottom of the view?
Any simple snippet would be most welcome.
Thank you!

Comment: I embedded the PageViewController inside another view controller and added a transparent view with a botton, at the bottom of this view controller, which stands on top of the PageViewControoler. It works but I do not find it a very elegant approach.

Answer (score 0):

1. In viewDidLoad, add the button to the UIPageViewController's view.
2. In viewDidAppear, bring the button to front

```

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // Add the button
  [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  // Bring it to front so it appears in front of the UIPageControl
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];
}
```

```